# How to handle earphones button clicks?

Tags: android, onclick

I have this code to handle button clicks from earphones. The problem is that my priority is low and when i click the button the radio turns on. I want to be able to give priority to my app. I tried to increase the setPriority number but it does not work.

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE) {
            // do something
            Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
```

//Code in other class

```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
        MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
        filter.setPriority(1000); **//increasing this does not work**
        registerReceiver(r, filter);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get media buttons in the background or only when your app is in the foreground? Are you building a media app or something else entirely?

Comment: Only when my app is in foreground...I am building something that when I click the button sends a Toast message to my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot register a receiver for `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` with `registerReceiver` as it is handled separately by the Media framework to dispatch to the correct media app as described in the [Responding to Media Buttons guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons.html).

However, in the case where you want to handle it in the foreground, you don't need to use `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` at all as all `KeyEvent`s are first sent to the active `Activity` via [`onKeyDown()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) (and `onKeyUp()`). Therefore you can handle the `KeyEvent` directly:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, 
            KeyEvent event) {
  // This is the center button for headphones
  if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: But I implement that method outside the onCreate. How do I call him inside the onCreate method?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in `onCreate`. With this code, anytime your Activity is on screen, you'll intercept the `PLAY_PAUSE` key.

Comment: If you debug your application, does `onKeyDown()` get called with some other `getKeyCode()`? Maybe your headset is different from others.

Comment: It gets called with the action_down and action_up at the same time. Because I press and release

Comment: Yes, that's how KeyEvents work. Generally if you want to intercept the play/pause button, you do your work on the down action. It certainly sounds like you are getting KeyEvents then, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when i click the play/pause button nothing happens, until the radio of my phone starts playing. I think its a problem of priority what do you think?

Comment: Are you shure that the method onKeyDown does not need to be put anywhere? I put the method bellow onCreate is that rigth?

Comment: It needs to be the Activity that is visible, the order of methods doesn't matter. Like I said, you should debug your app and check what key code you're getting when you click the button on your headset.

Comment: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK, scanCode=164, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=159233107, downTime=159233107, deviceId=6, source=0x101 }  this appears

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to use [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK)

Comment: It works, dude you are a genius. Thank you so much, I wish I would be like you.